# MEMORY_MANAGEMENT BSoD on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, memory, motherboard, power-supply, bsod

I have a new machine running Windows 8.1 with the following brand new components:

- Intel Core i5-6500
- 8GB DDR4 2400MHz Kingston HyperX Fury (one 8GB module)
- ASRock Z170m-ITX/ac
- Samsung 850 EVO 250GB
- EVGA 220-G2-0550-Y1 (EVGA SuperNOVA 550 G2 PSU)

I have been having trouble with the system getting a `MEMORY_MANAGEMENT` BSoD on occasion. I can make it get this error in a minute or two by running PRIME95.

What I've tried:

- Disabling Intel SpeedStep (locks CPU to 3.19GHz)
- Lowering RAM frequency to 1600MHz
- Ensuring all cables are firmly connected
- Reinstalling Windows 8.1

Unfortunately I don't have any other components to swap out and test with. I also would NOT like to start an RMA process for any of said components as the system must be in working condition.

I have a valid concern in this system. The way the power supply is connected to the 20-pin of the motherboard leaves 4 pins (2 2-row) floating. The power supply is modular and at the other end by the power supply all pins seem to be connected. You can see the motherboard-end visualized below.

[image]

Comment: share the dmp file from C:\Windows\Minidump

Answer (score 1):

The problem seemed to be resolved by updating to the latest BIOS (1.8 at the time of this post)! Going over two hours long with various PRIME95 tests.

ASRock actually has a tool that you can run from within Windows and it will reboot into the BIOS to update it. The motherboard came shipped with version 1.0 BIOS which according the information on the site didn't support the higher frequencies of DDR4.

Update: Went over 30 hours continuous stressing. Definitely seems like it's fixed.

Comment: I'm glad it seems to be more stable now, but have you also ran Memtest86 to make sure you don't have a faulty RAM stick?

Comment: @DrZoo I unfortunately cannot do that as the machine is put back into use. If any problems occur I will be sure to use Memtest.

Comment: @Jire please make your answer as the accepted answer, as when browsing through the questions people (like me) think the question is still unanswered until we click on it and have a look.